# recursion using for do loop (pascal)

Tags: recursion, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to use the concept of recursion but using for do loop. However my program cannot do it. For example if I want the output for 4! the answer should be 24 but my output is 12. Can somebody please help me?

```
 program pastYear;

 var
   n,i:integer;


 function  calculateFactorial ( A:integer):real;

 begin
   if A=0 then
     calculateFactorial := 1.0
   else
     for i:= A downto 1 do
     begin
       j:= A-1;
       calculateFactorial:= A*j;
     end;
   end;

   begin
     writeln( ' Please enter a number ');
     readln ( n);
     writeln ( calculateFactorial(n):2:2);
     readln;
   end.
```

Comment: `j` isn't declared anywhere. Also, `A` never changes in your loop, therefore `j` (from `j := A-1` never changes, and, therefore, `A*j` never changes. Your factorial program returns `A*(A-1)`.

Comment: Recursion would be `A*calculateFactorial(A-1)`, no loop necessary.

Comment: Guys thanks for helping me out. I finally got the answer I've been looking for. About the loop I know that we can do recursion without it but the question from my lecturer want us to use the loop so that's why.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code.

1. First of all it doesn't compile because you are accessing the undefined variable `j`.
2. Calculating the factorial using a loop is the *iterative* way of doing it. You are looking for the *recursive* way.

What is a recursion? A recursive function calls itself. So in your case `calculateFactorial` needs a call to itself.

How is the factorial function declared?

[image]

In words:

> The factorial of `n` is declared as
>
> - 1 when `n` equals `0`
> - the factorial of `n-1` multiplied with `n` when `n` is greater than `0`

So you see the definition of the factorial function is already recursive since it's referring to itself when `n` is greater than `0`.

This can be adopted to Pascal code:

```
function Factorial(n: integer): integer;
begin
  if n = 0 then
    Result := 1
  else if n > 0 then
    Result := Factorial(n - 1) * n; 
end;
```

No we can do a few optimizations:

- The factorial function doesn't work with negative numbers. So we change the datatype from `integer` (which can represent negative numbers) to `longword` (which can represent only positive numbers).
- The largest value that a `longword` can store is 4294967295 which is twice as big as a `longint` can store.
- Now as we don't need to care about negative numbers we can reduce one  `if` statement.

The result looks like this:

```
function Factorial(n: longword): longword;
begin
  if n = 0 then
    Result := 1
  else 
    Result := Factorial(n - 1) * n; 
end;
```

Comment: It is possible to optimize the code by declaring `n` parameter and function result as word/longword etc. (>=0) with simultaneous removing of redundant `if n > 0 then`. It is possible to check if the parameter is >= 0 once at the line where the function is first called. However I upvote your answer